# Any idea why Scrapy Response.follow is not following the links?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have created a spider as you would see below. I can get links from homepage but when I want to use them in function scrapy doesn't follow the links. I don't get any http or server error from source.

```
 class GamerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'gamer'
allowed_domains = ['eurogamer.net']
start_urls = ['http://www.eurogamer.net/archive/ps4']

def parse(self, response):
    for link in response.xpath("//h2"):
        link=link.xpath(".//a/@href").get()
        content=response.xpath("//div[@class='details']/p/text()").get()

        yield response.follow(url=link, callback=self.parse_game, meta={'url':link,'content':content})

    next_page = 'http://www.eurogamer.net'+response.xpath("//div[@class='buttons forward']/a[@class='button next']/@href").get()
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)


def parse_game(self, response):
    url=response.request.meta['url']
    #some things to get

    rows=response.xpath("//main")
    
    for row in rows:
        #some things to get

        yield{
            'url':url
            #some things to get
        }
```

Any help?

Comment: I'm not following your issue with what you've written as your code. I've run what you've given and seems to be doing exactly what it should be doing. In your function parse_game you're actually not interacting with the HTML for each individual page. You're yielding a dictionary of the URL of that specific page, which you've created via the meta argument. It's actually not necessary to use the meta tag for that. response.url will give you the URL of the response.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for your comment. I can get urls from each page there is no problem at all. But I want to move the link I took and crawl the page link. 

For example-> first page has 100 title and each title has a href url. I want to get urls one by one and move to this url. In this new url I will crawl the data I need. I get Link but I cannot send them to parse_game func.   

I used yield response.follow for different websites and worked perfectly. But not working now.

Comment: Each link is being processed, but you're not doing anything in parse_game that has anything to do with each individual URL. You're looping over the rows list. Which only has one item in it, if you look at the individual URLs HTML. You're then yielding a dictionary with the url variable as a value which is defined as response.request.meta['url']. Which is referencing the link variable from the parse function. You aren't really interacting with any data from the individual URLs in parse_game. It would perhaps help what data exactly you're needing from the URLs and show an attempt at that.

Comment: I got the point now. Thanks. I add all the values and now it works perfect. Cheers!